# trying to connect to viagogo API using oAuth

Tags: php, oauth

I've been trying to access the viagogo API but I get a 500 error, i'm using the code sample here:

www.dropbox.com/s/8fqfkkmdcvjtzxt/apipublicaccess.php

Surprisingly, this code works fine here:
http://mynameisroman.com/apipublicaccess.php

but not here :

http://www.smapin.com/apipublicaccess.php

Any ideas ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: It never works with smapin.com AFAIK. Never. Until the error is fixed.

Comment: hi , thanks for your response but i don't understand it :/

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that you need to change the following lines of code to contain valid Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

```
$VIAGOGO["CONSUMERKEY"]="3o*******0jUQ";
$VIAGOGO["CONSUMERSECRET"]="Cv3*************dx0J";
```

Comment: I would say it's a safe bet that the OP did this so we wouldn't see their key/secret.